# How can Top Navigation component from UI Kitten can be used in React Native Stack Navigator as a custom header

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator, react-native-ui-kitten

I Have a custom header component designed using UI Kitten "Top Navigation" component (link below to examples) i would like to use that as a header on main page instead of the header Stack Navigator provides

https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/top-navigation/overview#topnavigationaction

lets say use custom "Top Navigation" component called `AppHeader` in `NotificationScreen`

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import routes from './routes';
import AppHeader from '../components/AppHeader';
import NotificationScreen from '../screens/notification/NotificationScreen';
import UserProfileScreen from '../screens/userProfile/UserProfileScreen';

const {Navigator, Screen} = createStackNavigator();

const StackNavigatorPage = () => (
  <Navigator>
    <Screen name={routes.NOTIFICATION_SCREEN} component={NotificationScreen} />
    <Screen name={routes.USER_PROFILE_SCREEN} component={UserProfileScreen} />
  </Navigator>
);

export default StackNavigatorPage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import routes from './routes';
import AppHeader from '../components/AppHeader';
import NotificationScreen from '../screens/notification/NotificationScreen';
import UserProfileScreen from '../screens/userProfile/UserProfileScreen';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/dashboard/HomeScreen';

const {Navigator, Screen} = createStackNavigator();

const StackNavigatorPage = () => (
  <Navigator>
    <Screen
      name={routes.HOME_SCREEN}
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={({navigation}) => {
        return {
          header: () => <AppHeader navigation={navigation} />,
        };
      }}
    />
    <Screen name={routes.NOTIFICATION_SCREEN} component={NotificationScreen} />
    <Screen name={routes.USER_PROFILE_SCREEN} component={UserProfileScreen} />
  </Navigator>
);

export default StackNavigatorPage;
```